# Separate statistics on sites from Domain Access

Tags: 7, domain-access, nodes

Is it possible to separate statistics (like number of views) on shared node on few sites while using [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module, so the same node can be viewed like 50 times on site1 and like 80 times on site2, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tested this but you could maybe use separate database tables with different prefixes for the tables that the statistics module provides (accesslog, node_counter).

So your tables might be something like:

- site1_accesslog
- site1_node_counter
- site2_accesslog
- site2_node_counter

The [domain_prefix](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_prefix) module handles that. This module was a sub-module included in the main domain access module for Drupal 6 but was separated in Drupal 7.

There is also an [issue here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1953292) which seems to indicate you can use a small snippet of code in a custom module for this instead of using this drupal.org module, which is seemingly not well supported currently.

Keep in mind this is a fairly advanced usage of Drupal so I advise caution and lots of testing. Having said that though the tables you want to split are low risk compared to say the node or users tables.